# How to SSH into a remote from another remote using VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

My workflow is: I ssh into machine A from my local, then into machine B from machine A.
I wish to develop on machine B using VScode remote functionality but this two-level ssh doesn't look straight forward in VScode  and a google search didn't yield much info on it either.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The key word is `ProxyJump` here.

`ssh hostb -o ProxyJump=hosta`

For using it with vscode, you should edit your `.ssh/config`

```
HOST my_alias_name_for_host_a
  hostname ip_or_hostname
  user my_username_on_host_a

HOST my_alias_name_for_host_b
  hostname ip_or_hostname
  user my_username_on_host_b
  ProxyJump my_alias_name_for_host_a
```

vscode will work without even knowing that there is an intermediate host